# Sensor simulator build fails with LNK1112 error

Tags: visual-studio, movesense

I'm trying to build and run the sensor simulator by following the steps from here: http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/getting_started/#build-commands-sensor-simulator

I have:

1. Pulled the repo
2. Created simuBuild folder
3. Run `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DMOVESENSE_CORE_LIBRARY=../MovesenseCoreLib/ ../samples/blinky_app`
4. Then opened the `Project.sln` file
5. Selected Movesense as Startup project

Now when I try to run it with `Debug` -> `Start new instance`, I get the following error: `movesense-coreD.lib(ResourceClient.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'`. How do I resolve this?

I also tried to set the `Linker` -> `Command line: Additional Options` to `%(AdditionalOptions) /machine:x86` but that also fails with similar but slightly different error: `Movesense.dir\Debug\App.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86`

Comment: Any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Had a same issue. Downgrading to **Visual Studio 2017** helped. Obviously it is not working on 2019 version.